# How to send and receive data from an android app to a hardware(microcotroller)?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I am developing a project which communicates over wifi. My project is about motor control with ARM CORTEX M0 processor. I want to send data from my mobile(android app) to the processor to increase or decrease the speed with the +/- symbol or to blink a LED or something like that and I need to receive data(for eg I programmed the processor to send the speed from controller or the motor is on or off) from processor and that need to be displayed in android app.

We are using Qualcomm Longsys GT1216 module attached to the processor and that creates the wifi connection to the mobiles. I want to develop an app that connects with that wifi to send and receive data to and from the controller. Is there any source code available to develop an app such like that.

Answer (score 0):

i can only suggest that for that purpose you can use websockets + json or yaml.
It is full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection. 
You should strongly prefer wss:// protocol over the insecure ws:// transport. Like HTTPS, WSS (WebSockets over SSL/TLS) is encrypted.
For transport i am using https://libwebsockets.org/ for linux but there are also version for android.
I have made one little project (IP relay) based on this technology. Linux system on one side and cortex M0 + board with LAN and TCP/IP stack on other side.
You should to know that it is big job. 1. You can start with standard socket TCP connections. 2. Implement client and server appl.
3. Implement json or yaml parser and then switch to websockets.